# Catching close tab event in a Safari extension

Tags: safari, safari-extension

I cannot find something like "closeTab" event in the [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH17-DontLinkElementID_23).

I've tried:

injected.js

```
window.addEventListener("unload", function(){
  // Probably closed.
  // Now I need to tell it to the global page.
}, false);
```

but I can't find a way to send a message from within an injected script to the global page. [Messages and Proxies](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH14-SW1) mentions only other way around.

Answer (score 3):

For Safari 5.1 onwards, they added a [tab close event](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html) that you can listen for and handle in the usual way.

Answer (score 2):

You can dispatch a message from an injected script to a global page like so:
`safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("messageName", messageData);`

(Your global page must have something to capture these events):

```
// register for message callbacks from the injected script
safari.application.addEventListener("message", respondToMessageFunction, false);
```

As far as how to capture "tab closed" events... your guess is as good as mine. I am actually trying to find that answer myself currently.

Answer (score 1):

use the "validate" event in background to detect tab switches, for example

```
var popupBackground = {

    initialised : false,
    activeTab : null,
    numberOfTabs : null,


    _init : function() { 
        var that = this;

        // on browser initialise reset data
        localStorage.clear();

        // this initialises the popup dialogue
        localStorage["popupOpened"] = false;



        // register listeners for application messaging
        safari.application.addEventListener("command", function(event){
            that.handleCommand(event);
        }, false);

        safari.application.addEventListener("validate",function(event){
            that.validateCommand(event);
        }, false);

        safari.application.addEventListener("message", function(event){
            that.handleMessage(event);
        }, false);

    },


    _getActiveTab : function(){
        return safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab;
    },


    // commands are validated before being excecuted
    validateCommand : function(aEvent) {
        var that = this;

        // all commands should have the identifier specified in Extension Builder
        if (aEvent.command === "togglePopup") {
            // check that there is an active tab    
            if (!aEvent.target.browserWindow.activeTab.url) {
                aEvent.target.disabled = true;
            } else {
                aEvent.target.disabled = false;
            }
        }


        // this is a hack for detecting tab switches, safari does not have a dedicated API like Chrome 
        if(this.activeTab !== null){
            if(this.activeTab !== this._getActiveTab()){
                $.each(safari.application.browserWindows, function(aIndex, aWindow) {
                    $.each(aWindow.tabs, function(aIndex, aTab) {
                        if(typeof aTab.page !== "undefined"){
                            //  message all tabs about the focus switch event
                            if (aTab !== that._getActiveTab()) {
                                aTab.page.dispatchMessage("tabUnfocused");
                                // set the popup status (incase tab closed with open popup)
                                localStorage["popupOpened"] = false;
                            }else{
                                aTab.page.dispatchMessage("tabFocused");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
        // set the new active tab
        this.activeTab = this._getActiveTab();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add listeners directly to the events, but so far I haven't found the correct one to detect when a tab is closed.

```
window.onload = function ( event ) {
   safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("onLoad","it's alive!!"); }

window.onfocus = function ( event ) {
   safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("onFocus","it's alive!!"); }

window.onblur = function ( event ) {
   safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("onBlur","it's alive!!"); }

window.onunload = function ( event ) {
   safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("onUnload","it's alive!!"); }

window.ondrop = function ( event ) {
   safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("onDrop","it's alive!!"); }

window.onpagehide = function ( event ) {
   safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("onPagehide","it's alive!!"); }

window.onpageshow = function ( event ) {
   safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("onPageshow","it's alive!!"); }

window.onbeforeunload = function ( event ) {
   safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("onBeforeunload","it's alive!!"); }

window.onchange = function ( event ) {
   safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("onChange","it's alive!!"); }

window.onemptied = function ( event ) {
   safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("onEmptied","it's alive!!"); }

window.onopen = function ( event ) {
   safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("onOpen","it's alive!!"); }

window.onended = function ( event ) {
   safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("onEnded","it's alive!!"); }

window.onerror = function ( event ) {
   safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("onError","it's alive!!"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

So far I haven't found a way for a tab to tell the global page that it's been (or is about to be) closed. One crappy workaround is to set up a timer on the global page that will check periodically whether any tabs have been closed. The following simplistic code will log when a tab is closed in the active window:

```
var tabs = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.tabs;
var myTimer = setInterval(function (){
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        if (app.activeBrowserWindow.tabs[i] !== tabs[i]) {
            console.log('A tab was closed.');
        }
    }
    tabs = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.tabs;
}, 1000);
```

This example is pretty useless, as it doesn't provide any information about the tab that was closed, and it will yield a false positive when a tab is merely moved.